# Remove line breaks in text area

Tags: javascript

How to detect line breaks in text area using Java script?
If two continuous blank lines present in text area delete one blank line and if only single line present delete it too.

Can any one help me on this? Currently I can able to delete single lines only.

```
Line 1


Line 2

Line3
```

should be converted to:

```
Line 1

Line 2
Line3
```

Comment: Mind sharing ur code? u should be able to achieve this using basic regex

Comment: Do you mean case like this: https://jsfiddle.net/6bvzwftv/ ?

Comment: What if there are three contiguous blank lines?

Comment: If there are three also delete one blank line and keep two

Comment: So is the correct definition of the desired behavior to "replace any *n* newlines with *n-1* newlines"?

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! We will be glad to help you if you get stuck on a specific programming problem, but we are not here to design your site or write your code for you. Please see [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [What topics can I ask about here](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use regular expressions to capture and replace patterns in a string. e.g.

```js
value.replace(/(\n\n?)\n+/g, '$1');
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    output = document.getElementById('output');

output.value = input.value.replace(/(\n\n?)\n+/g, '$1');
```

```css
textarea { height: 180px; float: left; }
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
one return

two returns


three returns



four returns
</textarea>

<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

[» Regex 101](https://regex101.com/r/sHnP5Y/2)

---

**edit:** The description was unclear, only ever removing one line break doesn't sound useful in the real world so I'll leave the original answer intact.  Regarding, *"I need to del one blank line alone in case of 3 or 4 blank lines"* - you mean the following then...

```js
value.replace(/(\n*)\n/g, '$1');
```

```js
var input = document.getElementById('input'),
    output = document.getElementById('output');

output.value = input.value.replace(/(\n*)\n/g, '$1');
```

```css
textarea { height: 180px; float: left; }
```

```html
<textarea id="input">
one return

two returns


three returns



four returns
</textarea>

<textarea id="output"></textarea>
```

Comment: I there are three blank line will it delete one blank line or will it delete two.

Comment: I need to del one blank line alone in case of 3 or 4 blank lines

Comment: It is working!! Thanks  a lot..But can you explain replace(/(\n*)\n/g, '$1'); what this line actually does??Thanks in advance

Comment: It matches at least one `\n` line break character at the end of a sequence and greedily "captures" any number of line breaks proceeding it - that may include none.  The capture group (i.e. any number of new lines minus one) is then injected into the replacement string denoted by the `$1`.

Answer (score 0):

Use regex to match more than two new lines

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
  $('textarea').change(function () {
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(/\n{3,}/g, "\r\n"));
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<textarea></textarea>
```

---

My code is in jQuery but all you need is this part: `value.replace(/\n{3,}/g, "\r\n")`

Comment: I'm not understanding this `$` notation. Is that some kind of archaic notation they used in the past?

Comment: He wants to delete single newlines. Does your code do that?

Comment: @torazaburo Yes, it used to. Now it will leave single empty line

Comment: @torazaburo It's called jQuery library and it's actively used now. It's just faster for me. All you need is `value.replace` part

Comment: No, it's not actively used, except by maintenance programmers working on systems which were built a decade ago. You might as well suggesting using COBOL. But whether or not you like jQuery or think it's obsolete or whatever, jQuery solutions are not welcome in answers unless the OP has explicitly requested them, or tagged his/her question as such.